# Can a site detect and block another for requesting a picture many times?

Tags: image, request

I'm depending on my users uploading image links, not image files. So my site actually requests this links from these external sites by including them on an  element and getting the src from the database.

Could sites detect they are receiving lots of "requests" (no idea if it's the right term) and block your url from doing more requests?

If they can, how many times would go unnoticed? Also are there policies like having to add a link to the source or something?

Comment: Yes, they can. No, we can't tell you what the limit is, because that's not public information. You have to join the Secret Society of Evil Web Scrapers for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites can detect and block your IP address, especially if you are sending a lot of requests that could slow down their site and cause performance issues on their end. Having users post links shouldn't be any issue though.

Comment: I imagined so, what about using php to upload the image to your server. Is it common to do this or may it be prohibited by particular website's policies?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you are doing with the images and who owns the rights to the images. A website can put whatever it wants in its policies/terms of use, but those don't usually hold to much weight. As far as uploading the images, I suppose you could do that, but that won't stop a site from blocking interaction with your server.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, hotlinking to files such as images can be detected and blocked. How many times can you do it? That depends on the limitations set by the website hosting the files you are hotlinking. There isn't really a definitive answer for every server about the limitations.